Why can't I use the emerald package on overleaf?
I'm trying to use the jd font (this one) on overleaf and it just doesn't compile. I managed to use the code on the link I just posted on TexMaker just fine.
On the first compile on overleaf the code reported it couldn't find the emerald.sty, then I downloaded this file from the main website and uploaded it to my project. Still nothing.
The log file says:
Font shape `T1/fjd/m/n' undefined

 
‪./main.tex‬
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

the code is:
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}}
\setkomafont{section}{\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\Large}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\section*{JD}
\subsection*{\textbackslash ECFJD}
\normalfont\ECFJD
    \huge{Primeira lista de módulo \\ Equações e gráficos}
\normalfont 
\newpage
\normalfont

\end{document}


emarald is not in texlive, just installing emarald.sty will not make it so you would need the fonts themselves the fd files, the font metrics and other things

unrelated but size commands such as \huge do not take an argument. \huge{Primeira lista de módulo \\ Equações e gráficos} is the same as \huge Primeira lista de módulo \\ Equações e gráficos and will make all text for the rest of the document huge.

so you would essentially need all the files from https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/emerald.zip  not just emerald.sty but setting that up on a remote server like overleaf may be tricky

if you place all the files from the package and the fonts into your project folder on overleaf, you can add the line \pdfmapfile{+emerald.map} along with the usual \usepackage into the preamble of your document. that should work, if you're compiling with pdftex (which is default on overleaf). but David may know some reason it won't. (that is, I'd expect it to work, but if he would expect it not to, I maybe should adjust my expectations.)

Look at the page on CTAN, namely https://ctan.org/pkg/emerald
I add a screenshot:

The license doesn't allow free distribution, so TeX Live cannot include it and Overleaf is based on TeX Live.
Complain with the maintainer.
